# How can I make the jQuery MultiSelect widget read-only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, multi-select

How can I make Eric Hynds' [MultiSelect](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) plugin for jQuery UI read-only? I know how to disable the widget, but I would like to display its contents without the user being able to change anything.

Comment: when you say make it readonly, do you mean make the checkboxes disabled?  If not, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Rooster Make it impossible to change the selection, which would entail disabling the checkboxes yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SEE THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3jr2v/132/)

basically, just pass a class you can target to the multiselect when you create it, then using that targeted class set disabled to true on all the inputs within the wrapper.

```
$("#jquery_fun").multiselect({classes:'jquery_fun'});
$('.jquery_fun').find('input').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: Will get back to you once I have the time to work on this problem again, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rooster solution causes a javascript error in IE8 when it tries to move the focus to a disabled input.
If you only want to display the selected value and no display the options, you can use the following code:

```
$("#myMultiselect").multiselect({
    multiple: false,
    header: true,
    selectedList: 1,
    open: function () {  
        $("#myMultiselect").multiselect("close");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#users").multiselect({classes:'multiselect-container'});
     $('label').find('input').each(function(){
     $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This answer looks like it is just [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18189728/8517948) with arbitrary class/ID selectors replaced with different arbitrary selectors. Can you [edit] it to elaborate more on how it differs from the linked answer?

Comment: I am here disbaling the options of multiselect not the multiselect itself, that's is used to pass the existing values to the backend, and back end will not throw validation error that user field is required.

Answer (score -3):

You can disable the control this way:

```
$("#myMultiselect").multiselect('disable');
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as the OP explicitly says he doesn't want to disable the widget.